# Manually add a fee in woocommerce - add_fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add an order manually to **WooCommerce**.
Everything is working fine except the adding fee. It doesn't add a fee to the order:

```
$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( 1, 2 ); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
$order->add_fee('discount', -10, true, 'standard' );
$order->calculate_totals();
$order->update_status("Processing", 'Order from mobile application', TRUE);
```

So the order is added, but i can not add a `fee(discount)` to the order.

Thank you for your help in advance! :)

Comment: See this very useful and functional answer: [Woocommerce Add Fee Outside of the Cart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37089760/3730754)

Answer (score 2):

after lots of hours of research and forum I found the solution, a work around. To add manually an order item with the value -10

```
    $item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order->id, array(
        'order_item_name' => "The discount",
        'order_item_type' => 'fee'
    ) );
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', wc_format_decimal( -10) );
```

Comment: Fee is an amount of money charged for a particular piece of work or for a particular right or service, and not supposed to be negative.