# How do you add a new Line Item(non product)/Fee to a existing Order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

o/

Working on a minor project, and I'm creating a WC order from the admin area (programmatically), and i want to add a line item(Non product/fee to the order after it been created, but how exactly do i do that?
I create a order by doing:

```
        $address = array(
            'first_name' => $sBillingFirstName,
            'last_name'  => $sBillingLastName,
            'company'    => $sBillingCompanyName,
            'email'      => $sBillingEmail,
            'phone'      => $sBillingPhone,
            'address_1'  => $sBillingAddress1,
            'address_2'  => $sBillingAddress2,
            'city'       => $sBillingCity,
            'state'      => '',
            'postcode'   => $sBillingZipcode,
            'country'    => $sBillingCountry,
            );
        $oOrder = wc_create_order();

        $oOrder->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
        $oOrder->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
```

and normally i would just do add_fee, as seen below to add a "non product" lineitem/fee, but since i dont have a cart object - what am i supposed to do?

```
wc->cart->add_fee("deposit", 200);
```

but i don't have a cart object, so how do i go about creating a the deposit in my new order?

Comment: I think that in WC2.7 it will be `$order->add_item()` but I'm not sure of the details.

Comment: You can use [WC_Abstract_Order add_fee() method,](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_add_fee) but you will need to set a **`$fee` object** in this method… The functional solution is in this thread: [**Woocommerce Add Fee Outside of the Cart**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37089760/3730754) …

Comment: Thank  you @LoicTheAztec, was just what i was looking for !